# Check whether there is at least one occurrence of all the elements in the main array inside the sub array identified by an identifier javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, foreach

```
let mainList = [ 2, 3, 5];
let subList = [
        {
            id: 23,
            name: "ABC",
            parent_id: 2
        },
        {
            id: 25,
            name: "DEF",
            parent_id: 2
        },
        {
            id: 26,
            name: "GHI",
            parent_id: 3
        }
    ];
```

I need to check whether there is atleast one occurrence of all the elements in the mainList inside the subList identified by `parent_id`.

How I am currently achieving this is

```
 let matchFound = true;
   mainList.forEach(mainItem => {
        matchFound =
            matchFound &&
            Boolean(
                subList.find(
                    sub_item =>
                        mainItem === sub_item.parent_id
                )
            );
    });
```

Would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I'd turn the `subList` into a `Set` of `id`s, and then check that every item in the `mainList` is included in the set:

```js
let mainList = [2, 3, 5];
let subList = [{
    id: 23,
    name: "ABC",
    parent_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 25,
    name: "DEF",
    parent_id: 2
  },
  {
    id: 26,
    name: "GHI",
    parent_id: 3
  }
];
const parentIdSet = new Set(
  subList.map(({ parent_id }) => parent_id)
);
const hasAll = mainList.every(item => parentIdSet.has(item));
console.log(hasAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `subList` isn't very large, I'd just use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const mainList = [2, 3, 5];
const subList = [{ id: 23, name: 'ABC', parent_id: 2 }, { id: 25, name: 'DEF', parent_id: 2 }, { id: 26, name: 'GHI', parent_id: 3 }];
const matchFound = mainList.every(
  mainItem => subList.some(
    subItem => mainItem === subItem.parent_id
  )
);

console.log(matchFound);
```